# Customize the grand total in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi

How to customize the grand total from sum to percentage of a column 1 without changing the values in column 1?

For Example:- I have a data

[image: Input Data]

Required output should be :-

[image: Output Required in Power BI]

Grand total of column value 1 = (value 1/ value 2)*100.

Comment: Sorry to say but a total of a column is the total of THAT column, not a number you wold like it to be. Is you need this you can make a measure. This is not going to line up in your table but shown as a seperate visual. What you proposing is (in my opinion) confusing to end user: how do they know what you mean by it?

Comment: Actually,It's a client result which they have already created on excel in same format. I am just automating it in power BI.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different column with the formula `(value 1/ value 2)*100`.

You will then need to unpivot/pivot things to get the data in the format which has Dove, Loreal, etc and the new calculation as columns. So you will be able to easily plot them in a matrix.

I won't call this as a solution, but I think this is the most efficient workaround. Let me know if it helps in any way.